# c++ Remove everything in string prior to sequence including sequence

Tags: c++, string, find

I've been writing a program that receives data from other sources across a network, and I need to sanitize the data before I send it to be processed. Previously, I had been doing it based on size, as below:

```
char data[max_length];
boost::system::error_code error;
size_t length = sock->read_some( boost::asio::buffer( data ), error );
std::stringstream ss;
for( int i = 0; i < max_length; i++ ) {
    ss << data[i];
}
std::vector<int> idata;
std::string s2 = ss.str();
s2.erase( 0, 255 );
```

But the headers I need to remove are of variable length. So after doing some digging, I found I could remove them by finding the sequence of characters I know they'll end in - in this case `\r\n\r\n` - and removing everything up until then using size_t like so:

```
size_t p = s2.find( "\r\n\r\n" );
s2.erase( 0, p );
```

But that still leaves the `\r\n\r\n`  at the beginning of my string which, at best, throws off my data handling later, and at worst, might cause issues down the line, as there are segments of my program that don't respond well to whitespace.

So my question is this: Is there a better way I could be doing this that will remove up to and including the specified sequence of characters? Can I just do `p = p + 4;` ? is that even possible with the size_t type?

Comment: `But that still leaves the \r\n\r\n at the beginning of my string which`  Are you saying that the `erase` doesn't work?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No he's saying that since `std::string::find()` returns the index of the *first* character of the matching subsequence, the specified string will still be left at the beginning after the `erase()` call. Meaning only everything *before* it was erased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can write `p + 4`, since `size_t` is an (unsigned) integer type.

By the way, you might also want to pass `data` directly into a `std::string` constructor, rather than use `std::stringstream ss`.

**Edit:** To explain in more detail, it would look something like this:

```
char data[max_length];

// Read data and ensure that it is null-terminated ...

std::string s2(data); // Call the std::string constructor that inputs a null-terminated C string.

size_t p = s2.find("\r\n\r\n");
s2.erase(0, p + 4);
```

Comment: What do you mean pass data directly to std::string? you mean just doing std::string s2 = data.str(); ?

Comment: @Oblivious12 He means `std::stringstream ss(data);`.